# Efficient way to compute number of matchings between two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join, innodb

**Description**

I have a MySQL table like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick1` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick2` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick3` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick4` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick5` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick6` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19675 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Let's also asume we have the following values already stored in DB:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ticket_id |   ticket_number   | pick1 | pick2 | pick3 | pick4 | pick5 | pick6 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 655       | 08-09-21-24-46-52 | 8     | 9     | 21    | 24    | 46    | 52    |
| 658       | 08-23-24-40-42-45 | 8     | 23    | 24    | 40    | 42    | 45    |
| 660       | 07-18-19-20-22-31 | 7     | 18    | 19    | 20    | 22    | 45    |
| ...       | ...               | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   |
| 19674     | 06-18-33-43-49-50 | 6     | 18    | 33    | 43    | 49    | 50    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Now, my goal is to compare each ticket with each other one in the Table (except itself), in terms of their respective values in `ticket_number` field (6 elements per set, split by `-`). Put differently, for instance, imagine I compare `ticket_id = 655` with `ticket_id = 658`, in terms of the elements in their respectives `ticket_number` fields, then I will find that elements `08` and `24` appear in both sets. If we now compare `ticket_id = 660` with `ticket_id = 19674`, then we have that there is only one coincidence: `18`.

What I am actually using to carry out these comparisons is the following query:

```
select A.ticket_id, A.ticket_number, P.ticket_id, P.ticket_number, count(P.ticket_number) as cnt from ticket A inner join ticket P on A.ticket_id != P.ticket_id
where 
((A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick1,2,0), "%"))
+ (A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick2,2,0), "%"))
+ (A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick3,2,0), "%"))
+ (A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick4,2,0), "%"))
+ (A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick5,2,0), "%"))
+ (A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick6,2,0), "%")) > 3) group by A.ticket_id
having cnt > 5;
```

That is, first I create a `INNER JOIN` concatenating all rows with different `ticket_id` and then I compare each `P.pickX` (`X=[1..6]`) with the `A.ticket_number` of the resulting `INNER JOIN` operation, and I count the number of matchings between both sets.

Finally, after executing, I obtain something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----+
| A.ticket_id |  A.ticket_number  | P.ticket_id |  P.ticket_number  | cnt |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----+
| 8489        | 14-21-28-32-48-49 | 2528        | 14-21-33-45-48-49 | 6   |
| 8553        | 02-14-17-38-47-53 | 2364        | 02-30-38-44-47-53 | 6   |
| 8615        | 05-12-29-33-36-43 | 4654        | 12-21-29-33-36-37 | 6   |
| 8686        | 09-13-29-34-44-48 | 6038        | 09-13-17-29-33-44 | 6   |
| 8693        | 01-10-14-17-42-50 | 5330        | 01-10-37-42-48-50 | 6   |
| ...         | ...               | ...         | ...               | ... |
| 19195       | 05-13-29-41-46-51 | 5106        | 07-13-14-29-41-51 | 6   |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----+
```

**Problem**

The problem is that I execute this for a table of `10476 rows`, resulting in more tan 100 Million `ticket_number` vs `pickX` to compare, lasting around 172 seconds in total to conclude. This is too slow.

**GOAL**

My goal is to make this execution as fast as possible so as to be completed in less than a second, since this must work in real-time.

Is that possible?

Comment: Having column names with numbers in it is almost always a sign of bad table design.

Comment: So, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, change your table design. You need another table for your `picks`, whatever that is.

Comment: Well, probably `picks` can be avoided in the equation, since we are only comparing elements in `ticket_number` sets for each couple of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the current structure then change pick1..6 to tinyint type instead of varchar

TINYINT(1) stores the values between -128 to 128 if it is signed. And then your query won't have that concat with `%` which is the cause of slow run.

Then, these two queries will give you the same result

```
select * FROM ticket where pick1 = '8';
select * FROM ticket where pick1 = '08';
```

This is the sql structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick1` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick2` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick3` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick4` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick5` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `pick6` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I think, you even can remove the `zerofill`

if this doesn't work, change the table design.

Comment: Now I have tried:

`select A.ticket_id, A.ticket_number, P.ticket_id, P.ticket_number, count(P.ticket_number) as cnt from ticket A inner join ticket P on A.ticket_id != P.ticket_id
where 
((A.ticket_number like P.pick1)
+ (A.ticket_number like P.pick2)
+ (A.ticket_number like P.pick3)
+ (A.ticket_number like P.pick4)
+ (A.ticket_number like P.pick5)
+ (A.ticket_number like P.pick6) > 3) group by A.ticket_id
having cnt > 5;`


... but seems not to work, since no rows are returned.

Comment: Anyway, I'm totally open to changing the structure of the table and the query. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` -- that is the _one_ use for the "(n)" in integers.

Answer (score 1):

How big can the numbers be?  Looks like 50.  If the answer is 63 or less, then change the format to this:

All 6 numbers are stored in a single `SET ('0','1','2',...,'50')` and use suitable operations to set the nth bit.

Then, comparing two sets becomes `BIT_COUNT(x & y)` to find out how many match.  A simple comparison will test for equality.

If your goal is to see if a particular lottery guess is already in the table, then index that column so that a lookup will be fast.  I don't mean minutes or even seconds, but rather a few milliseconds.  Even for a billion rows.

The bit arithmetic can be done in SQL or in your client language.  For example, to build the `SET` for (11, 33, 7), the code would be

```
INSERT INTO t SET picks = '11,33,7'  -- order does not matter
```

Also this would work:

```
... picks = (1 << 11) |
            (1 << 33) |
            (1 <<  7)
```

A quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE `setx` (
  `picks` set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO setx (picks) VALUES ('2,10,6');
INSERT INTO setx (picks) VALUES ('1,3,5,7,9'), ('2,4,6,8,10'), ('9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10');
SELECT picks, HEX(picks+0) FROM setx;
+----------------------+--------------+
| picks                | HEX(picks+0) |
+----------------------+--------------+
| 2,6,10               | 222          |
| 1,3,5,7,9            | 155          |
| 2,4,6,8,10           | 2AA          |
| 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 3FF          |
+----------------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hi Rick. Thank you for the answer. I will have a look and come back with the result. :)